# Do Intel's SIMD instructions affect the parity flag?

Tags: assembly, intel, sse, simd, parity

I'm reading [Intel's software developers manual](http://www.intel.com/Assets/en_US/PDF/manual/253665.pdf).

It has this to say about the parity flag:

> Set if the least-signif
>   icant byte of the result 
>   contains an even number of 1 bits; cleared otherwise.

I'd like to know whether or not SIMD (specifically SSE) instructions affect the parity flag. For example, if I use the PEXTRB instruction, will that set the parity flag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The entry for `PEXTRB` says

> Flags Affected
>   None.

So no.

In general only the main ALU group (`and`/`or`/`add` etc, that set) and shift/rotate set parity to whatever the parity is (there are some more). Moves generally don't affect flags. SSE instructions generally don't affect flags, with some obvious exceptions. `COMISS` and friends affect parity, but in a completely different way.

If you want the parity of a `pextrb`ed byte, you can just `test` it.

Comment: What do you mean by `test`ing it?

Comment: @Venemo Use the TEST instruction. Eg `test al,al; jp parity_set`.

Answer (score 1):

According to "Intel 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual vol 2" which is easily downloadable from the intertubes:

```
Flags Affected
None.
```